# Ejabberd with Jitsi Videobridge ejabberd_service Failed external component handshake authentication

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I want to use the Ejabberd with Jitsi Videobridge. When i configured the Ejabberd service and start the Jitsi Videobridge both side thrown the exception.
My ejabberd.yml

```
 port: 5275
 ip: "0.0.0.0"
 module: ejabberd_service
 access: all
 shaper_rule: fast
 ip: "127.0.0.1"
 privilege_access:
    roster: "both"
    message: "outgoing"
    presence: "roster"
 delegations:
    "urn:xmpp:mam:1":
      filtering: ["node"]
    "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub":
      filtering: []
 hosts:
   "jitsi-videobridge.[mydomain]":
   password: "587828"
```

start Jitsi Videobridge like below

```
HOST="127.0.0.1"
DOMAIN="mydomain"
PORT="5275"
SECRET="abcdef123"
JVB_HOME="/usr/src/ejabberd/jitsi-videobridge"

mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.args="--host=$HOST --domain=$DOMAIN --port=$PORT --secret=$SECRET" -Djava.library.path=$JVB_HOME/lib/native/linux-64 -Djava.util.logging.config.file=$JVB_HOME/lib/logging.properties -Dnet.java.sip.communicator.SC_HOME_DIR_NAME=.jitsi-videobridge
```

The ejabberd exception:

> 17-10-17 23:29:44.719 [info] <0.336.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:302 (<0.521.0>) Accepted connection 127.0.0.1:39506 -> 127.0.0.1:5275
>
> 2017-10-17 23:29:44.721 [info] <0.522.0>@ejabberd_service:handle_auth_failure:173 (tcp|<0.521.0>) Failed external component handshake authentication for jitsi-videobridge.mydomain from 127.0.0.1: not authorized
>
> 2017-10-17 23:55:20.459 [info] <0.336.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:302 (<0.549.0>) Accepted connection 127.0.0.1:51580 -> 127.0.0.1:5275
>
> 2017-10-17 23:55:20.474 [info] <0.550.0>@ejabberd_service:handle_auth_failure:173 (tcp|<0.549.0>) Failed external component handshake authentication for jitsi-videobridge.mydomain from 127.0.0.1: not authorized
>
> 2017-10-17 23:55:25.484 [info] <0.336.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:302 (<0.551.0>) Accepted connection 127.0.0.1:51618 -> 127.0.0.1:5275
>
> 2017-10-17 23:55:25.487 [info] <0.552.0>@ejabberd_service:handle_auth_failure:173 (tcp|<0.551.0>) Failed external component handshake authentication for jitsi-videobridge.mydomain from 127.0.0.1: not authorized

Videobridge  exception like :
SEVERE: not-authorized, host:127.0.0.1, port:5275

```
org.xmpp.component.ComponentException: not-authorized
        at org.jivesoftware.whack.ExternalComponent.connect(ExternalComponent.java:243)
        at org.jivesoftware.whack.ExternalComponentManager.addComponent(ExternalComponentManager.java:242)
        at org.jivesoftware.whack.ExternalComponentManager.addComponent(ExternalComponentManager.java:222)
        at org.jitsi.meet.ComponentMain$3.call(ComponentMain.java:270)
        at org.jitsi.meet.ComponentMain$3.call(ComponentMain.java:255)
        at org.jitsi.retry.RetryStrategy$TaskRunner.run(RetryStrategy.java:193)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Can anybody help?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

orgin:
   hosts:
       "jitsi-videobridge.[mydomain]":
       password: "587828"

the correct configure:

```
 hosts:
   "jitsi-videobridge.[mydomain]":
    password: "587828"
```

Comment: Could you explain?